# Calculating distance: method "must return a value"?

Tags: c++, distance, square-root

I'm trying to call the `dist()` method however I keep getting a error saying that `dist()` must return a value.

```
// creating array of cities
double x[] = {21.0,12.0,15.0,3.0,7.0,30.0};
double y[] = {17.0,10.0,4.0,2.0,3.0,1.0};

// distance function - C = sqrt of A squared + B squared

double dist(int c1, int c2) {
    z = sqrt ((x[c1] - x[c2] * x[c1] - x[c2]) + (y[c1] - y[c2] * y[c1] - y[c2]));
    cout << "The result is " << z;
}

void main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    execute(a, 0, sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));

    int  x;

    printf("Type in a number \n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    int  y;

    printf("Type in a number \n");
    scanf("%d", &y);

    dist (x,y);
}
```

Comment: Read about Order of Operations.  `x[c1] - x[c2] * x[c1] - x[c2]` does not do what you probably intend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are outputting "The result is z" to STDOUT but not actually returning it as the result of the `dist` function.

So

```
double dist(int c1, int c2) {

    z = sqrt (
         (x[c1] - x[c2] * x[c1] - x[c2]) + (y[c1] - y[c2] * y[c1] - y[c2]));
      cout << "The result is " << z;
}
```

should be

```
double dist(int c1, int c2) {

    z = sqrt (
         (x[c1] - x[c2] * x[c1] - x[c2]) + (y[c1] - y[c2] * y[c1] - y[c2]));
      cout << "The result is " << z;
    return(z);
}
```

(assuming you still want to print it).

---

**Alternatively**

You can declare that `dist` doesn't return a value using `void`:

```
void dist(int c1, int c2) {

    z = sqrt (
         (x[c1] - x[c2] * x[c1] - x[c2]) + (y[c1] - y[c2] * y[c1] - y[c2]));
      cout << "The result is " << z;
}
```

**See:** [C++ function tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/).

Answer (score 7):

Either change the return type to void:

```
void dist(int c1, int c2) {

  z = sqrt ((x[c1] - x[c2] * x[c1] - x[c2]) +
           (y[c1] - y[c2] * y[c1] - y[c2]));
  cout << "The result is " << z;
}
```

or return the value at the end of the function:

```
double dist(int c1, int c2) {

  z = sqrt ((x[c1] - x[c2] * x[c1] - x[c2]) +
           (y[c1] - y[c2] * y[c1] - y[c2]));
  cout << "The result is " << z;
  return z;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `dist` function is declared to return a `double` but returns nothing.  You need to explicitly return `z` or change the return type to `void`

```
// Option #1 
double dist(int c1, int c2) {
    z = sqrt (
         (x[c1] - x[c2] * x[c1] - x[c2]) + (y[c1] - y[c2] * y[c1] - y[c2]));
      cout << "The result is " << z;
    return z;
}

// Option #2
void dist(int c1, int c2) {
    z = sqrt (
         (x[c1] - x[c2] * x[c1] - x[c2]) + (y[c1] - y[c2] * y[c1] - y[c2]));
      cout << "The result is " << z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add following line:
return z;
-1 for such question.

Comment: It may be a very simple question, but it was asked quite well.

Comment: You really think it's necessary to berate him in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined dist to return double ("double dist"), on the bottom of dist() you should do "return dist;" or change "double dist" to "void dist" - void means it doesnt need to return anything.